# EF include list is always null

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

By some reason EF wont load the included list properly so it ends up being null all the time.

Here is the entities i'm using:

```
    [Table("searchprofilepush")]
public class SearchProfilePush
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public bool Push { get; set; }
    public int UserPushId { get; set; }
    public UserPush UserPush { get; set; }
    public int SearchProfileId { get; set; }
    public SearchProfile SearchProfile { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SearchProfileMediaTypePush> SearchProfileMediaTypePush { get; set; }
}


[Table("searchprofilemediatypepush")]
public class SearchProfileMediaTypePush
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MediaTypeType MediaType { get; set; }
    public bool Push { get; set; }
    public int SearchProfilePushId { get; set; }
    public SearchProfilePush SearchProfilePush { get; set; }
}
```

Then when i'm trying to do this:

```
 var searchProfilePush = _dataContext.SearchProfilePush.Include(w => w.SearchProfileMediaTypePush).FirstOrDefault(w => w.AccountId == accountId && w.SearchProfileId == searchProfileId);
```

My included list is always null.

[image]

I guess it's some obvious reason why this doesn't work but i just can't figure it out.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the sql query:

SELECT \"Extent1\".\"id\", \"Extent1\".\"accountid\", \"Extent1\".\"push\", \"Extent1\".\"userpushid\", \"Extent1\".\"searchprofileid\" FROM \"public\".\"searchprofilepush\" AS \"Extent1\" WHERE \"Extent1\".\"accountid\" = @p__linq__0 AND @p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL AND (\"Extent1\".\"searchprofileid\" = @p__linq__1 AND @p__linq__1 IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 1

EDIT 2:
I have now mapped my entities both way and the list is still always null.

[image]

Edit 3:

This is how i created my database tables.
[image]

Comment: How is this navigation property mapped? What is the generated SQL query?

Comment: I added an edit. It seems that it doesn't join at all :( @DevilSuichiro

Comment: so how is the navigation property mapped?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation I read for loading related entities has some differences with the sample code and your code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

First, when you define your ICollection, there is no keyword virtual:

```
public virtual ICollection<SearchProfileMediaTypePush> SearchProfileMediaTypePush { get; set; }
```

Next, in the example close to yours, where they load related items using a query, the first or default is not using a boolean expression. The selective expression is in a where clause:

```
 // Load one blogs and its related posts 
    var blog1 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

So you can try:

```
var searchProfilePush = _dataContext.SearchProfilePush
.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountId && w.SearchProfileId == searchProfileId)
.Include(w => w.SearchProfileMediaTypePush)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Can you make these two changes and try again?

Comment: i don't think this is it. The virtual keyword is if you want to lazyload the entities and i don't want to do that. Setting a where before the first or default just makes it grab a list and then take the first in that list instead of just limit it before.

Comment: about the `virtual` keyword : it does not seem to me that the related entites are lazy-loaded if you use `.Include`

Answer (score 0):

A few things will be an issue here. You have no keys defined or FKs for the relationship:

```
[Table("searchprofilepush")]
public class SearchProfilePush
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int AccountId { get; set; }
   public bool Push { get; set; }
   public int UserPushId { get; set; }
   public UserPush UserPush { get; set; }
   public int SearchProfileId { get; set; }
   public SearchProfile SearchProfile { get; set; }
   public ICollection<SearchProfileMediaTypePush> SearchProfileMediaTypePush { get; set; }
}


[Table("searchprofilemediatypepush")]
public class SearchProfileMediaTypePush
{
   [Key]    
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public MediaTypeType MediaType { get; set; }
   public bool Push { get; set; }
   public int SearchProfilePushId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("SearchProfilePushId")]     
   public SearchProfilePush SearchProfilePush { get; set; }
}
```

Personally I prefer to explicitly map out the relationships using EntityTypeConfiguration classes, but alternatively they can be set up in the Context's OnModelCreating. As a starting point have a look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx for basic EF relationship configuration.

for a SearchProfilePush configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SearchProfilePush>()
  .HasMany(x => x.SearchProfileMediaTypePush)
  .WithRequired(x => x.SearchProfilePush)
  .HasForeignKey(x => x.SearchProfilePushId);
```

Comment: Foreign keys are established by convention. You don't explicitly have to specify them unless you don't want to follow the usual EF convention.

Comment: Regarding your updated example: Remove one of the mappings. I.e. use the .HasMany().WithRequired()  on the parent entity, and remove the .HasRequired().WithMany() on the child. I've seen issues with double-mapping.  Also, given the Serial type on your PK you probably also should have the DatabaseGeneratedOption set to "Identity" for your PK fields.